# Find text between parentheses and delete rest

Tags: regex, find-and-replace, adobe-indesign

I have paragraphs like this:

> **(قَوْلُهُ: وَمَسْحُ الرَّأْسِ)** إنَّمَا أَخَّرَهُ؛ لِأَنَّهُ مَمْسُوحٌ وَالْأَعْضَاءُ مَغْسُولَةٌ فَلَمَّا كَانَتْ مُتَّفِقَةً فِي الْغَسْلِ جَمَعَ بَيْنَهَا فِي الذِّكْرِ.
> (قَوْلُهُ وَالْمِرْفَقَانِ وَالْكَعْبَانِ يَدْخُلَانِ فِي الْغَسْلِ) قَالَ زُفَرُ - رَحِمَهُ اللَّهُ تَعَالَى - لَا يَدْخُلَانِ؛ لِأَنَّ الْغَايَةَ لَا تَدْخُلُ تَحْتَ الْمُغَيَّا كَاللَّيْلِ فِي الصَّوْمِ قُلْنَا نَعَمْ لَكِنْ الْمَرَافِقُ وَالْكَعْبَانِ غَايَةُ إسْقَاطٍ فَلَا يَدْخُلَانِ فِي الْإِسْقَاطِ؛ لِأَنَّ قَوْلَهُ {وَأَيْدِيَكُمْ} [المائدة: ٦] يَتَنَاوَلُ كُلَّ الْأَيْدِي إلَى الْمَنَاكِبِ فَلَمَّا قَالَ إلَى الْمَرَافِقِ خَرَجَ مِنْ أَنْ يَكُونَ دَاخِلًا تَحْتَ السُّقُوطِ؛ لِأَنَّ الْحَدَّ لَا يَدْخُلُ فِي الْمَحْدُودِ فَبَقِيَ الْغَسْلُ ثَابِتًا فِي الْيَدِ مَعَ الْمَرَافِقِ وَفِي بَابِ الصَّوْمِ لَيْسَتْ الْغَايَةُ غَايَةَ إسْقَاطٍ وَإِنَّمَا هِيَ غَايَةُ امْتِدَادِ **(قَوْلُهُ: وَمَسْحُ الرَّأْسِ)** الْحُكْمِ إلَيْهَا؛ لِأَنَّ الصَّوْمَ يُطْلَقُ عَلَى الْإِمْسَاكِ سَاعَةً فَهِيَ غَايَةُ إثْبَاتٍ لَا غَايَةُ إسْقَاطٍ وَاعْلَمْ أَنَّ الْغَايَاتِ أَرْبَعٌ: غَايَةُ مَكَان، وَغَايَةُ زَمَانٍ، وَغَايَةُ عَدَدٍ، وَغَايَةُ فِعْلٍ، فَغَايَةُ الْمَكَانِ مِنْ هَذَا الْحَائِطِ إلَى هَذَا الْحَائِطِ وَغَايَةُ الزَّمَانِ {ثُمَّ أَتِمُّوا الصِّيَامَ إِلَى اللَّيْلِ} [البقرة: ١٨٧] وَكِلَاهُمَا لَا يَدْخُلَانِ فِي الْمُغَيَّا وَغَايَةُ الْعَدَدِ لَهُ مِنْ دِرْهَمٍ إلَى عَشْرَةٍ وَأَنْتِ طَالِقٌ مِنْ وَاحِدَةٍ إلَى ثَلَاثٍ وَهِيَ لَا تَدْخُلُ عِنْدَ أَبِي حَنِيفَةَ وَزُفَرَ وَعِنْدَهُمَا تَدْخُلُ وَغَايَةُ الْفِعْلِ بِالْمَنْطُوقِيَّة السَّمَكَةَ حَتَّى رَأْسَهَا إنْ نَصَبْت السِّينَ دَخَلَتْ وَتَكُونُ حَتَّى بِمَعْنَى الْوَاوِ وَعَاطِفَةً، وَإِنْ خَفَضْتهَا لَمْ تَدْخُلْ وَتَكُونُ حَتَّى بِمَعْنَى إلَى، وَإِنَّمَا قَالَ يَدْخُلَانِ فِي الْغَسْلِ وَلَمْ يَقُلْ بِفَرْضِ غَسْلِهِمَا؛ لِأَنَّهُمَا إنَّمَا يَدْخُلَانِ عَمَلًا لَا اعْتِقَادًا حَتَّى لَا يَكْفُرَ جَاحِدُ فَرْضِيَّةِ غَسْلِهِمَا.
> **(قَوْلُهُ: وَالْمَفْرُوضُ فِي مَسْحِ الرَّأْسِ مِقْدَارَ النَّاصِيَةِ)** وَهُوَ رُبُعُ الرَّأْسِ وَالنَّاصِيَةُ هِيَ الشَّعْرُ الْمَائِلُ إلَى نَاحِيَةِ الْجَبْهَةِ وَالرَّأْسُ أَرْبَعُ قِطَعٍ النَّاصِيَةُ وَالْقَذَالُ وَالْفَوْدَانِ، فَقَوْلُهُ مِقْدَارَ النَّاصِيَةِ إشَارَةٌ إلَى أَنَّهُ يَجُوزُ أَنْ يَمْسَحَ أَيَّ الْجَوَانِبِ شَاءَ مِنْ الرَّأْسِ بِمِقْدَارِهَا وَإِنَّمَا قَالَ وَالْمَفْرُوضُ وَلَمْ يَقُلْ وَالْفَرْضُ؛ لِأَنَّ الْمُرَادَ كَوْنُهُ مِقْدَارًا لَا مَقْطُوعًا بِهِ؛ لِأَنَّ الْفَرْضَ هُوَ الْقَطْعُ حَتَّى إنَّهُ لَا يَكْفُرُ جَاحِدُ هَذَا الْمِقْدَارِ وَالتَّقْدِيرُ بِمِقْدَارِ النَّاصِيَةِ هُوَ اخْتِيَارُ الشَّيْخِ وَفِي رِوَايَةٍ مِقْدَارُ ثَلَاثَةِ أَصَابِعَ وَلَوْ أَدْخَلَ الْمُحْدِثُ رَأْسَهُ فِي الْإِنَاءِ يُرِيدُ مَسْحَهُ أَجْزَأَهُ عَنْ الْمَسْحِ وَلَا يَفْسُدُ الْمَاءُ عِنْدَ أَبِي يُوسُفَ.
> وَقَالَ مُحَمَّدٌ يَصِيرُ الْمَاءُ مُسْتَعْمَلًا وَلَا يُجْزِيهِ عَنْ الْمَسْحِ وَكَذَا الْخُفُّ عَلَى هَذَا الِاخْتِلَافِ.
> **(قَوْلُهُ: لِمَا رَوَى الْمُغِيرَةُ بْنُ شُعْبَةَ أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ - صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ - أَتَى سُبَاطَةَ قَوْمٍ إلَى آخِرِهِ)** فِي هَذَا الْحَدِيثِ سِتُّ فَوَائِدَ
> الجوهرة النيرة على مختصر القدوري - جـ 1(ص: 5)

I want to use GREP Find/Change in Adobe InDesign to keep the text that are between parentheses and delete the rest including parentheses.

I have tried the following query:
`(?<=\()[^()]+(?=\))`

But it is not working.

Comment: Can you maybe share a screenshot of your Find/Change window so that we can see what's there? Also, ```(?<=\()[^()]+(?=\))``` is finding all those words in parenthesis, but what replace do you use to try to keep only this?

Comment: Please **avoid** the "it's not working" phrase when asking question on website like this. Instead, always describe as accurately ass possible what exactly is not working. Hard to tell anything just with that. Especially that the regex itself seems correct for Perl syntax that InDesign apparently uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Find/Change should do what you need:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Find/Change window (if it is not yet open)
- Go to the ***GREP*** tab for advanced find and replace
- Find what: `.*?\((.+?)\)` this find everything but only the text inside the parentheses grouped
- Replace with: `$1` (or `$1~b` to have them each in a separate line, or add any delimiter you went them to have in between those pieces of text)
- <kbd>Chnage all</kbd>

[image]

---

That was assuming you mean InDesign's GREP Find and not the command like `grep` tool (you added the tag `grep` that has a description of "*grep is a Unix command-line utility*...").

If you actually meant the `grep` utility (then not sure what the `adobe-indesign` tag would mean) you can use something like this:

```
grep -oP "\(\K[^\)]+" inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Yes I am using Adobe InDesign and you query worked.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method : Extract the strings between the parenthesis to a file,
then remove the parenthesis.

The command can be such as :

```
grep -o -P "\(.+?\)" >file
```

Comment: From the `adobe-indesign` tag used it seems he's actually referring to Adobe InDesign GREP Find and not the Linux `grep`... But regardless, you're `grep` syntax doesn't seem to work, it outputs the whole text. This should work for him if he actually wanted Linux grep :  `grep -oP "\(\K[^\)]+" inputfile.txt > file.txt`

Comment: @YisroelTech: It worked on my grep, but thanks for the alternative syntax.

Comment: Odd. On which system are you? I'm not `grep` 3.7 on Ubuntu and see what I get https://imgur.com/a/VB0ZwbE

Comment: @YisroelTech: Mine is WSL Ubuntu very simple command `echo 'aa(bb)cc' | grep -o -E "\(.+\)"`. Shouldn't be affected by the text in Arabic.

Comment: Oh, I see what's the issue with yours. It only works if there is a single string in parentheses, otherwise it finds from the first `(` to the last `)` and in his text that's the whole thing (do `echo 'aa(bb)cc(ffff)ddd' | grep -o -E "\(.+\)"` to see what I mean) .Also, mine outputs the text with the parentheses already removed

Comment: @YisroelTech: I fixed the command, needed to use Perl syntax for non-greedy search to work. Your grep syntax is better, admittedly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145617/discussion-between-yisroel-tech-and-harrymc).